# Apache 2.0 - Disabling the HTTP TRACE and TRACK methods

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, http, perl

I use Apache 2.0 as HTTP server and specific purpose Perl-based HTTP clients. Until now I disable TRACE and TRACK methods using the following configuration in the httpd.conf file:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
>
> RewriteRule .* - [F]

**Questions**

1) In order to increase the performance, Could I replace the previous configuration by the following ?

> traceEnable off

2) Can "traceEnable off" command ensure that both TRACE and TRACK methods will be disabled?

3) Finally, do I need to append TRACE/TRACK disabling configuration in httpd.conf file since the HTTP server can be accessed only by Perl-based HTTP clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. According to the documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#traceenable TraceEnable Off will only disable the HTTP TRACE method. It does nothing to the TRACK method.
2. See 1.
3. If your server is public, then you should probably disable these methods.

In addition: since you seem to be paranoid (which can be a *good* thing!), I would upgrade to a later version of Apache as the final release of 2.0 has been made and no new bugs -- including security holes will be fixed.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response! The server upgrade is not in my responsibilities, so I have to work on Apache 2.0. ;) Anyway, I can not understand the TRACK command's effect on Apache since TRACK method is a Microsoft command that Apache doesn't support. Do you have an idea?

Comment: No idea. I'm not sure if it works, but maybe you can use `curl -X TRACK` to test whether Apache even responds to TRACK at all without any config? See http://blogs.plexibus.com/2009/01/15/rest-esting-with-curl/ for info on using CURL to test other HTTP methods.

Comment: I like curl! :) Nice and usefull command! Thank you!

Comment: Please let us know your findings! I run a few public Apache servers and am considering locking them down further. For example, I only enable the modules I really need (which is only about 6 or 7).

Comment: This is significantly belated, but Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) reports 501 - Not Implemented when I curl -X TRACK it.

Answer (score 4):

**Case A: TRACE directive**

Using the "traceEnable on" command in the httpd.conf file and running the following curl command:

> SITE=`http://www.server.my`; curl $SITE  -X **TRACE**

The response is:

```
TRACE / HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: curl/7.29.0 Host: http://www.server.my Accept: */*
```

In the other hand, if "traceEnable off" the previous curl command returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.63 OpenSSL/0.9.7d DAV/2 Server at http://www.server.my Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

which means that the TRACE enable directive is disabled. So, I think that the "traceEnable off" command is working properly.

**Case B: TRACK directive**

Using the "traceEnable on" command in the httpd.conf file and running the following curl command:

> SITE=`http://www.server.my`; curl $SITE  -X **TRACK**

The response is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>501 Method Not Implemented</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Implemented</h1>
<p>TRACK to / not supported.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.63 OpenSSL/0.9.7d DAV/2 Server at http://www.server.my Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Here is the conclusion of the previous testcase: **501 Method Not Implemented** . If you send a TRACE request to Apache, it will return that this method is not implemented. So, I think that we don't need to worry... This is confirmed by the next test case.

If "traceEnable off" then the previous TRACK request returns the same "not implemented" message.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>501 Method Not Implemented</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Implemented</h1>
<p>TRACK to / not supported.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.63 OpenSSL/0.9.7d DAV/2 Server at http://www.server.my Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

According to http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/ihsdiag/http_trace.html, even though apache server does not support the TRACK method natively, it is possible for plug-in modules to provide support for it. To disable this capability for plug-in modules, in addition to disabling the TRACE method we may have to disable TRACK method using the Rewrite module.

But if you don't install a TRACK plug-in into Apache there are not security issues. Is this assumption valid?

Comment: Yes: if you don't install (m)any modules you limit Apache's capabilities. Thoroughly check the documentation of the modules that you do install.